# How to get sum in group wise (group left) in Oracle BI publisher Reports

Tags: oracle, bi-publisher

Please check the image below. I want a group wise sum for each group.

[group wise sum of Oracle BI Publisher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgBL9.png)

Need the summary at the summary level

Answer (score 0):

```
<?sum(current-group()/FIELD)?>
```

Replace 'FIELD' by the name of the field you want to sum.

Answer (score 0):

example xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Generated by Oracle BI Publisher 12.2.1.4.0 -Dataengine, datamodel:__rakicd_WRK_aa_xdm -->
<DATA_DS>
<G_1>
<CS_ID>A</CS_ID><CS_NAME>A name</CS_NAME><CS_VALUE>10</CS_VALUE>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<CS_ID>A</CS_ID><CS_NAME>A name</CS_NAME><CS_VALUE>20</CS_VALUE>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<CS_ID>B</CS_ID><CS_NAME>B name</CS_NAME><CS_VALUE>10</CS_VALUE>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<CS_ID>B</CS_ID><CS_NAME>B name</CS_NAME><CS_VALUE>20</CS_VALUE>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<CS_ID>B</CS_ID><CS_NAME>B name</CS_NAME><CS_VALUE>30</CS_VALUE>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<CS_ID>C</CS_ID><CS_NAME>C name</CS_NAME><CS_VALUE>10</CS_VALUE>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<CS_ID>C</CS_ID><CS_NAME>C name</CS_NAME><CS_VALUE>20</CS_VALUE>
</G_1>
<G_1>
<CS_ID>C</CS_ID><CS_NAME>C name</CS_NAME><CS_VALUE>30</CS_VALUE>
</G_1>
</DATA_DS>

GrpSum [Advanced] = <?sum(current-group()/CS_VALUE)?>
Total [Advanced] = <?sum(//CS_VALUE[.!=’’])?>
```

rtf table
[image]

Result:
[image]